# Сглаживание показаний C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Снимаем в Unity координаты по оси X с тачпада

```
foreach(var th in Input.touches)
{
    float coordx = th.position.x
}
```

сoord x дергается сильно, когда ведёшь палец. Значения так или иначе выдает верные, но очень много высокочастотных помех. Как их отфильтровать, сгладить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел устройство тачпадов и их систему очищения от помех. Они просто берут три(есть вариации, но стандартно - три) значения координат пальца рядом и усредняют их. Таким образом помехи минимизируются, а нужная информация о местоположении пальца - сохраняется.

Код метода - принимает значения координат пальца, выдает усреднённые значения

```
float FilterX(float rawX)
{
    if (lowFilterX.Count > 3)
    {
        if (save == 0)
        {
        filterCoordX = 0;
        }
        else
        {
        filterCoordX = save;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < lowFilterX.Count; i++)
        {
            filterCoordX = (lowFilterX[1] + lowFilterX[2] + lowFilterX[3]) / 3;
        }
        save = filterCoordX;
        lowFilterX.Add(rawX);
        lowFilterX.RemoveAt(0);
        return filterCoordX;
    }
    else
    {
        lowFilterX.Add(rawX);
        return rawX;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос не понятен и твои намерения тоже. А потому предположу что это нужно для прокрутки сцены.

1. Нужно убедится что нажатие одно. Иначе как если игрок будет пятью сардельками двигать в разные стороны  ничего определить не получится.

   ```
   if (Input.touchCount == 1)
   ```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-touchCount.html

2. Найти смещение

   ```
   Input.touches[0].deltaPosition
   ```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-deltaPosition.html

3. Сдвигаем камеру на `deltaPosition` умножив ее на некий "Х"(быстрей или медленней)

Comment: Сожалею, что не смог донести до вас что мне необходимо. Это не то. Сейчас выложу ответ.